# MySQL: Not to duplicate data

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL statement that I want to use that will display the data in two different tables, but not have any duplicated data.

```
SELECT Customer.firstName, Customer.lastName, Purchase.productName, Purchase.productPrice
FROM Purchase
INNER JOIN Customer
```

This is currently the MySQL I am using and it does work, but it loads duplicated data which I do not want. I have looked around but not seeing a simple solution. Sorry in advance if it is a simple solution, been working for awhile and brain isn't really working.

Comment: When you use `inner join`, you should always have an `on` clause.  Although MySQL makes it optional, you should always have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind those tables via related columns.

Let's assume primary column of table `Customer` is named `ID` and customer ID is being held in a column named `customerID` in table `Purchase`:

```
SELECT Customer.firstName, Customer.lastName, Purchase.productName, Purchase.productPrice
FROM Purchase
INNER JOIN Customer 
ON Custormer.ID=Purchase.customerID
```